# Can one extend the explanations in Feynman's book "QED" to include spin?

Tags: quantum-spin, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics

Feynman's book QED is wonderful. Somewhere at the beginning, he writes that he does not take into consideration spin.

Is there a paper, a text or an explanation similar to that beautiful book but which *includes* the effects of spin?

Is there a way at all to reproduce all of Feynman's explanations while including spin?

To the moderators: I am not looking for a resource, but for a visual explanation that includes spin.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I can think of is Feynman's Dirac Memorial Lecture, which is on YouTube.